# How do I get the rightmost column to fill the remaining space?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Say I have a table with only three small columns. It looks untidy and unbalanced to have a narrow, tall table hugging the left side of my screen ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrZXp/)), so I'd like the table to cover the width of the page. However, when I set the table width to 100%, all the columns are stretched out as well, so now my data is spread thinly across the screen, which also looks untidy ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrZXp/1/)).

What I'm looking for is a solution where all the columns have the same size as they would have had if the table was `width: auto`, but the final column fills the remaining space on the screen. This is what Spotify does, for example:

[image: Spotify]

The "User" column will cover the remaining width, no matter what. Is there a relatively simple way of achieving this with HTML tables and CSS?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I have found a simple solution:

```
table td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

```css
body {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}

table {
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #222222;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

table td {
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

table td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}

table td:nth-child(odd), table th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

table tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Cardinality</th>
        <th>Price per item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pear</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>$3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sausage</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pineapple</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lightsaber</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$99 999</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This appears to work in my current scenario, but it looks like something that can cause unwanted side effects in other situations. If I stumble across any, I'll edit this answer.

#### Possible side effects

- Multi-word table cells will be wrapped into multiple lines to keep the column as narrow as possible. One solution is to use `white-space: nowrap` on the table cells, but that will hinder cells with lots of text from wrapping when they should.

Comment: try fill a product with 2 long words, the words will collapsed into the next line, you need a white-space:nowrap; to each td, check my answer

Comment: Thanks for the white-space: nowrap tip... that was what I was looking for!

Comment: If one of the earlier columns contains just an image then the image seems to shrink to a tiny size, even if nowrap is set.

Comment: If leading columns request a fixed width that is not honored any longer and they get squeezed as much as possible since the last column asks to be as wide as possible.

Comment: @legolas108 What if you add a `min-width` to those columns?

Answer (score 27):

If this is what you meant: [image]

Then I can achieve that using standard html table structure with the following css:

```
table {
  width:auto;
}
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
td:last-child {
  width:100%;
}
```

--EDIT : [work with your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrZXp/3/)

Comment: In my scenario, the last column is a multi-row column. This css fails to act as expected in this case. here is the sample code https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098150/874366

Comment: The width of the table will be over 100% of its parent if it has too much content.