# How to make the final TD element use up exactly all of the remaining width?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I found this SO question: [How do I get the rightmost column to fill the remaining space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137757/how-do-i-get-the-rightmost-column-to-fill-the-remaining-space)

Which seems to basically be exactly what I want. However, my layout is not appearing as I expected.

Part of my page looks like this:

```
<table id="Header" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="clsBorderColor" style="LEFT:10px; POSITION:relative; TOP:10px;">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4" >
   <table id="SearchParams" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="width:100%" class="clsBorderColor">
    <!-- A few rows and an ASP panel containing another row -->
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <table id="DisplayOptions" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="clsBorderColor">
    <tr>
     <td valign="middle" style="width:auto;">
      <asp:label id="lblRecordsCnt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Small">Records: </asp:label>
     </td>
     <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:auto;">
      # of records per page <asp:textbox id="txtNoOfRecords" tabIndex="7" CssClass="clsTextBox40" Runat="server"></asp:textbox>
     </td>
     <td valign="middle" style="white-space:nowrap;width:auto;">
      <asp:button id="cmdRefresh" tabIndex="8" runat="server" Text="Refresh" tooltip="Refresh"></asp:button>
     </td>
     <td valign="middle" style="white-space:nowrap;width:225px;" align="right">
      <asp:button id="cmdSearch" cssclass="clsButton60" runat="server" Text="Search" tooltip="Search"></asp:button>
      <input type="button" id="cmdClose" class="clsButton60" onclick="javascript:mfpOpenPopup('Default','foo');return false;" value="Close" title="Close" />
     </td>
     <td style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

(I hate to say it but`<table id="Header">` is actually contained in ANOTHER `<table id="Body">`, which has all of the same attributes and values. This is why both `SearchParams` and `DisplayOptions` are inside of `<td colspan="4">` tags.)

In the Design View in Visual Studio, it shows up pretty close to what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

But when I browse it in IE11 I get this:

[image]

The empty `<td style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>` element  is smooshing the rest of the row over. I've tried specifying hardcoded values for all the preceding `<td>` tags, but the end result is the same. I've also removed the `white-space:nowrap` and that doesn't seem to make a difference, either.

How can I make make this table use the entire width of the parent table, and more specifically how can I make the final `<td>` element use up whatever the the preceding elements don't require?

Comment: you should show us the html output, not your asp code. and eventually provide a jsfiddle or codepen that shows your bug ;)

Comment: Stupid question, but do you really need the last td? From the screenshot it looks like you can just remove it and let the table take on its natural width (not 100%).

Comment: If the last two buttons end up on the right side of the screen, you forgot to remove the `width:100%`... [Here, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqc06brr/2/).

Comment: @MrLister The last two buttons end up on the right side for the reason you mentioned earlier, the outer table already has a width of 100%

Comment: The inner table does not inherit the width from the outer table.

Comment: Ah, I think I somehow both missed your comment about removing the width *and* the Fiddler link :(

Comment: @MrLister you are correct the inner table doesn't inherit width. I originally styled the inner table to see it's border limits and saw full width (halfway through markup changes and must of still had 100% somewhere in the inner table) and assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white-space:nowrap literally prevents wrapping which could be applied on the columns you don't want "smushed".  Remove all the widths in that row and just give the last column in that nested table a width of 100% and apply no-wrap on the other columns...

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <table id="DisplayOptions" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="clsBorderColor">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Small">Records: </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="left" style="white-space: nowrap;"># of records per page
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" TabIndex="7" CssClass="clsTextBox40" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" TabIndex="8" runat="server" Text="Refresh" ToolTip="Refresh"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap;" align="right">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="clsButton60" runat="server" Text="Search" ToolTip="Search"></asp:Button>
                        <input type="button" id="cmdClose" class="clsButton60" onclick="javascript: mfpOpenPopup('Default', 'foo'); return false;" value="Close" title="Close" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Between this, and Lister's comments I was able to make it work. Thank you