# How to make the last column of a table fill the remaining space?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a fixed width and I want the size of all columns to be automatically adjusted to their content. However, if there is little content for the columns, I want only the last column to fill the remaining space.
So basically, I want the table to behave like a normal table with no fixed width. In cases where the table does not fill the maximum width of the parent, the last column should expand.
Furthermore, the table should have several rows, where the cells of the same column are exactly below each other.

Here are some examples of how the table is supposed to look:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum                               |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | Lorem | Lorem ipsum dolor sit            |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit | Lorem ipsum dolor sit | Lorem ipsum dolor sit |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit | Lorem ipsum dolor sit | Lorem ipsum dolor sit |
| amet, consetetur      | amet, consetetur      | amet, consetetur      |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The best solution I have found so far ([other question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137757/how-do-i-get-the-rightmost-column-to-fill-the-remaining-space)) uses `width: 100%;` on the table and the last cell and `white-space: nowrap;` on all cells. Problem with the solution is that the table becomes wider than it should because of the `white-space: nowrap;` when there is a lot of text, as you can see in the example:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This looks good:</p>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>This doesn't:</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have written my own answer using JS (see below). However, I would prefer a solution without JS.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Why the `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: If it was not there, the first two columns would be compressed.

Comment: @j08691 is correct `white-space: nowrap` means that your  `td` elements will spill out past your divs `500px` widths

Comment: I know that and that is my problem with the solution. But I have not yet found anything better that works

Comment: If you really do want to contain them in that 500px width and not have white space wrapped then you can apply `overflow-x: scroll;` to your div element;

Comment: Is there no other solution without the ```white-space: nowrap;``` where the width is maintained?

Comment: You could remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from the `td` and  then replace  `width: 100%;` from the `td:last-child` with `white-space: nowrap;` and it will look a bit better.

Comment: But then it would no longer work for cases with little text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now come up with my own solution using Javascript:

```js
let tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (table of tables) {
  let tableCs = getComputedStyle(table);
  let tableWidth = parseFloat(tableCs.width) + parseFloat(tableCs.marginLeft) + parseFloat(tableCs.marginRight);

  let parentCs = getComputedStyle(table.parentElement);
  let parentWidth = table.parentElement.offsetWidth - parseFloat(parentCs.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(parentCs.paddingRight);
  let remainingSpace = parentWidth - tableWidth;

  let cell = table.querySelector("td:last-child");
  if (cell && remainingSpace) {
    cell.style.width = (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(cell).width) + remainingSpace) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td>Lorem</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td></tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td></tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try flex. The key here is setting the `flex-grow` property of the last cell in a row to a high number (it defaults to 0).

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  display: contents;
}

tr {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;  /* for reasons I do not know right now, setting this to 100% does not work */
}

td {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

td:last-child {
  flex-grow: 100;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- You do not have to take a table, unless it semantically fits. -->
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: For tables with only one row this looks like a good solution. However, I want to have a table with multiple rows, while not losing the table property.

Comment: What do you mean by "*while not losing the table property*"?

Comment: I want the cells of the same column to be exactly below each other.

Comment: flex doesn't provide a table/grid layout, totally irrelevant

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Oh, _totally irrelevant_? My apology for sucking so much.

Comment: @NilsLindemann as you see your output doesn't look like a table as the OP wanted... ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Ok, @Remco646, you already solved it yourself, but still, here is my JavaScript solution:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  const container = document.querySelector('main');
  const tables = container.querySelectorAll('table');

  function width(elem) {
    return Math.round(elem.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }
  const table_max_width = 480; // or calculate this from the dom

  for (const table of tables) {
    const table_width = width(table);
    if (table_width !== table_max_width) {
      const last_cells = table.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
      const cell_width = width(last_cells[0]);
      // One pixel less, to fix display errors where text gets suddenly wrapped
      const cell_width_new = table_max_width - (table_width - cell_width) - 1;
      for (const cell of last_cells) {
        cell.style.width = `${cell_width_new}px`;
      }
      // Add back the pixel
      table.style.width = `${table_max_width}px`;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
```